# Error reading netcdf and hdf files using python

Tags: python, netcdf, hdf

I have the following code that would allow me to open `.nc` or `.h5` files, and would supposidly open its contents.

```py
import gdal
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas


def nch5read(fn, ncmaskscale=True):
    import netCDF4 as nc
    import h5py
    from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC

    d = {'VARS':{}, 'ATTRS':{}}
    if os.path.splitext(fn)[1] == '.nc':
        f = nc.Dataset(fn)
        f.set_auto_maskandscale(ncmaskscale)
        for i in f.ncattrs():
            try:
                d['ATTRS'][i] = f.getncattr(i)
            except:
                pass

        for i in f.variables:
            try:
                d['VARS'][i] = {'DATA':np.squeeze(f.variables[i][:]),
                'ATTRS':{j:f.variables[i].getncattr(j) for j in f.variables
                }}
            except:
                pass

    if os.path.splitext(fn)[1]== '.h5':
        f = h5py.File(fn)
        d['ATTRS']=dict(f.attrs)

        for i in f:
            try:
                d['VARS'][i] = {'DATA':np.squeeze(f[i][()]),
                'ATTRS':dict(f[i].attrs)}
            except:
                pass

    return d

fn = "cons_dom.nc"

d = nch5read(fn)
print(d)
```

I am using an example domestic water use file, `cons_dom.nc` obtained from this website `https://zenodo.org/record/897933#.YkH_SefMKUn` but when running the code, I get a blank result `{'VARS': {}, 'ATTRS': {}}`

Additionally, I tried adding a section for `.hdf` into the code

```py
import gdal
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas


def nch5read(fn, ncmaskscale=True):
    import netCDF4 as nc
    import h5py
    from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC

    d = {'VARS':{}, 'ATTRS':{}}
    if os.path.splitext(fn)[1] == '.nc':
        f = nc.Dataset(fn)
        f.set_auto_maskandscale(ncmaskscale)
        for i in f.ncattrs():
            try:
                d['ATTRS'][i] = f.getncattr(i)
            except:
                pass

        for i in f.variables:
            try:
                d['VARS'][i] = {'DATA':np.squeeze(f.variables[i][:]),
                'ATTRS':{j:f.variables[i].getncattr(j) for j in f.variables
                }}
            except:
                pass

    if os.path.splitext(fn)[1]== '.h5':
        f = h5py.File(fn)
        d['ATTRS']=dict(f.attrs)

        for i in f:
            try:
                d['VARS'][i] = {'DATA':np.squeeze(f[i][()]),
                'ATTRS':dict(f[i].attrs)}
            except:
                pass
# Segment added to read .hdf files
    if os.path.splitext(fn)[1]== '.hdf':
        f = SD(fn, SDC.READ)
        f.set_auto_maskandscale(ncmaskscale)
        for i in f.variables:
            try:
                d['VARS'][i] = {'DATA':np.squeeze(f.variables[i][:]),
                'ATTRS':{j:f.variables[i].getncattr(j) for j in f.variables}}
            except:
                pass
    return d

fn = "MCD12Q1.A2016001.h10v05.006.2018149125004.hdf"

d = nch5read(fn)
print(d)
```

But when I try running a sample `MODIS` file, `MCD12Q1.A2016001.h10v05.006.2018149125004.hdf` I get an error

```
File "C:\Users\Jay_Oliver\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\pyhdf\SD.py", line 3222, in _getattr
    index = a.index()
  File "C:\Users\Jay_Oliver\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\pyhdf\SD.py", line 1193, in index
    _checkErr('find', self._index, 'illegal attribute name')
  File "C:\Users\Jay_Oliver\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\pyhdf\error.py", line 23, in _checkErr
    raise HDF4Error(err)
pyhdf.error.HDF4Error: find (59): Invalid arguments to routine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nc_example.py", line 63, in <module>
    d = nch5read(fn)
  File "nc_example.py", line 52, in nch5read
    f.set_auto_maskandscale(ncmaskscale)
  File "C:\Users\Jay_Oliver\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\pyhdf\SD.py", line 1446, in __getattr__
    return _getattr(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\Jay_Oliver\Anaconda3\envs\rasterio\lib\site-packages\pyhdf\SD.py", line 3224, in _getattr
    raise AttributeError("attribute not found")
AttributeError: attribute not found
```

Comment: Are you sure the first part of the error traceback message is complete?  The very first error line should be in your code, not in the pyhdf package.

Comment: @JohnGordon that is all I get for the error traceback message. I believe that the error could be due to misuse of syntax that is not commonly used in the pyhdf package. It works just fine with `.h5` and `.nc` in the sense that it does not produce an error, but only produces an empty output.